# NodeJS localhost XMLHttpRequest cannot load link type="text/babel"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The same link to jsx file (with ReactJS code) is opened online fine, but NodeJS localhost opens it with an Error:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.../js/r1BodyBabel.js. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."
```

What is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

confident from your header request, it should take these permission

```
headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*" ,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET",
                "Access-Control-All-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
                   Content-Type, Accept, Key",
                "Content-Type" : 'multipart/form-data'
            }
```

and if you use a local-server you should add this tools 
when adding this tools to your chrome add your URL 
http://localhost:3000
[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Answer (score -1):

This is not a NodeJS or React/JSX problem. Chrome and other browsers runs withing the CORS limitations when loading the content directly off the filesystem.

You can just disable the Chrome CORS behavior with extensions. There are some of them and could be find by keyword "CORS".